# Saving NSNumber Array with Save-/Open-Panel

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsnumber, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

I'm trying to save a NSNumber Array, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I've got the code working for a single NSNumber:

```
- (NSData *)dataOfType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError {
     return [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:Number];
}

- (BOOL)readFromData:(NSData *)data ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError {
     [self setNumber:[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data]];
     return YES;
}
/*
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    [coder encodeObject:Number forKey:@"number"];
} */
/*
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    if (self) {
      self.Number = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"number"];
    }
    return self;
} */
```

Since it didn't work for NSNumber array I tried to use a NSMutableArray instead, but it doesn't work either:

```
- (NSData *)dataOfType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError {
    return [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:Array];
}

- (BOOL)readFromData:(NSData *)data ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError {
    [self setArray:[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data]];
    return YES;  
}
/*
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    [coder encodeObject:Array[0] forKey:@"one"];
    [coder encodeObject:Array[1] forKey:@"two"];
    [coder encodeObject:Array[2] forKey:@"three"]; 
} */
/*
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    if (self) {
        self.Array[0] = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"one"];
        self.Array[1] = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"two"];
        self.Array[2] = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"three"];
    }
    return self;
} */
```

So what am I doing wrong?

edit: seems like the encodeWithCoder and initWithCoder aren't needed

Comment: I don't think you need those `encodeWithCoder` or `initWithCoder` methods, do you?  Are they ever invoked?

Comment: I wonder about that too. I tried to follow a few tutorials, but none of them ever mentioned when they are invoked. (It works without them for the single number.)

Comment: I don't think there is any reason your code won't work.  An alternative approach would be to store the array in a `.plist` using `writeToFile:atomically:`.

Comment: Now that's the problem. It should work, but it doesn't.

Comment: I solved the problem myself. I'll post the answer soon.